# How to activate Emoji Picker in KDE Plasma 5.18 on Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: updates, kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I am wondering about the new update on KDE Plasma 5.18.0, there are some improvements and new features as mentioned [here](https://kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.18.0).

There is one thing that I am interested in, named Emoji Picker. The official site of KDE said that emoji picker will be triggered and pop up by pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>). But I don't know, I get nothing pop up while trying that keyboard combination on an editor, a text input field or such.

Previously, I was in KDE 5.16.x as default when installing Kubuntu 19.10. Heard about that news, then I full-upgraded my system using this way,

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

After that, I restarted my computer, logged in again, tried emoji picker, and nothing worked. Any help, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the issue is just because I installed Latte dock and one if its function replace emoji picker default shortcut. So the workaround is just to go to **System Settings** > **Shortcut** > **Global Shortcuts** > **Emoji Selector**.

Then click Emoji Selector *global* cell, select Default. A dialog will be prompted to confirm reassigning Emoji selector for that shortcut. Click yes to confirm.

There it is. Now I can use Emoji Selector everywhere in the system just by clicking <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>).

In my case, Latte dock replaced the shortcut and caused the issue. Maybe in your side, it will be different app, just follow my way to solve that in case you find the same issue as me.

Comment: I don't see "Emoji Selector"

Comment: same here, which packages are required to see it?

Answer (score 2):

On Arch with KDE Plasma, I had to install the `noto-fonts-emoji` package because otherwise most of them would appear blank.
On Ubuntu it looks like it's [`fonts-noto-color-emoji`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/focal/fonts-noto-color-emoji).

And then using the shortcut defined in the *System Settings → Shortcut → Global Shortcuts → Emoji Selector* menu as mentioned should work.

Answer (score 1):

KDE Plasma uses `ibus-ui-emojier-plasma` emoji picker which uses `ibus` emoji tables.

You don't have to install `ibus` for that, as these tables are in the `ibus-data` package.

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-data fonts-recommended
```

Note: the emoji fonts themselves are in `noto-fonts-emoji` (on Ubuntu) or `fonts-noto-color-emoji` (on Debian). These should already be included in `fonts-recommended`.

Comment: There's no difference between Debian 11 and Kubuntu 20.04 (as observed on my end). Package [fonts-recommended] is not installed. Package [fonts-noto-color-emoji] is installed (same package name on both distribution). Thank you for the explanation about the [ibus-data] package.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to have a look at [this](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts).
It's a collection of patched ("nerd") fonts.

Comment: Nerd fonts are a bunch of patched fonts with special glyphs for command-line fancifying tools such as [Airline status bars](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) etc. They're cool but don't have much to do with emojis at all.