# How to Add Emoji into Latte Dock on Kubuntu 21.10 KDE Plasma 5.24

Tags: kubuntu, applet, latte-dock

This is what I am trying to do. I am trying to add emoji into my latte dock design.

I bring up emoji selector application and I have founded my emoji.
If I copy it(single click and CRTCL + C), this what happens:

[image: emoji selector]

When paste it into my latte dock virtual desktop bar, this what happens:

[image: virtual desktop bar]

Here are the links for Virtual Desktop and Latte dock design I am using for my kubuntu 21.10 Desktop theme:

[wsdfhjxc/virtual-desktop-bar](https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/virtual-desktop-bar)

[Glass Spider Latte Layout](https://store.kde.org/p/1646931/)

I have tried researching the solution. The only article I have found is this:

[How to activate Emoji Picker in KDE Plasma 5.18 on Kubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210596/how-to-activate-emoji-picker-in-kde-plasma-5-18-on-kubuntu-19-10)

I am not sure the article above is the issue i am having.
if i could get help, i would really appreciated.